# React Table: use multiple array

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I want to use a React-Table with a lot of data.

Here is my data:

```
myData: {Array1:[{},{},...], Array2:[{},{},...], Array3:[{},{},...]}
```

So in my React-Table component, I do this:

```
<ReactTableFixedColumns data={myData} />
```

but it is not working. If I do `*"data={myData.Array1}"*`, I can see my data present in `Array1`. But I want to have all my data, not only the data in `Array1`.

Comment: If the data in the arrays are all of the same format then you should combine them into one array and pass it to the table.

Comment: The data in the arrays are not all of the same format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine all the data into one array:

```
const data = Object.values(myData).flatMap(arr => arr)

<ReactTableFixedColumns data={data} />
```

Comment: @Gargantua this is nice answer,  what did you exactly want?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Because, My array1 as 30 data. All arrays combined equals to 100 data. So, my table have 100 row, not the 30 I need

Comment: @Gargantua you said  You wanted  to have all data, not only the data in "Array1"

Comment: Yes, your solution work (sorry for the late answer)